# Is there a feature built into Docker for monitoring and ensuring containers are always running?

Tags: docker, monit

My first thought would be Monit, which I use to monitor other processes.

Is there a different way of doing this in the Docker universe?

I wish to monitor both the Docker daemon and specific containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to containers there is the `--restart` flag for the `run` command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies-restart.

On more modern Linux distributions (such as CoreOS and Ubuntu) you get systemd and Upstart managing the daemons.

For example, on Ubuntu, the default Upstart configuration for Docker has the `respawn` stanza (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) enabled by default.

In systemd land, CoreOS has something like this to launch the Docker daemon: https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/blob/bed6ea27913a1d9595b62e05174ac4a841c7fabb/app-emulation/docker/files/docker.service. You can customize (https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-docker.html) the systemd units that get used and use the `Restart=` option (http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=) to achieve similar functionality.

However, both of these options don't do any native alerting or messaging. Though, you could probably configure some sort of "mailer" unit that runs `OnFailure=` of the Docker systemd unit. But I'd call this out of scope for Docker and the init systems.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I just need to throw a basic Monit alert on the daemon then, and it (and upstart) will do the rest.